# Hitting 'start' from current slide it starts the slide show from the beginning instead of current slide?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2007

Every time I hit start from current slide it starts the slide show from the beginning. I'm only trying to edit this one slide so I don't want to have to watch the entire show multiple times. Why won't it start from the current slide?

Answer (score 1):

When you click start from current slide, make sure in the bottom left of the screen it actually shows the slide number you want (for example slide 6 of 10) - just scrolling through the slides in the editing window does not always advance this, so click the slide in the left hand overview pane to be sure.

Comment: The correct slide number shows

Comment: OK, try `Shift+F5` (I am presuming Windows here) - this is the keyboard shortcut to start from current slide.

Comment: I tried that already. It only does it for this one slide for some reason. I have even deleted the slide and started over. It still does the same thing.

Comment: Weird, just as an experiment, create a new blank presentation with the same number of slides, go to the same slide number and see if it works correctly. If it starts from the beginning then it's a bizarre PowerPoint issue, if it works as expected then there is something specific to that one file that has gone awry.

Comment: Yeah it worked fine in the blank presentation

Comment: Got to be something broken with that file - any chance it was created in an older version of PowerPoint and then dragged up to 2007? One solution may be to copy the contents of each slide into a new blank presentation and save it as a fresh file.

Answer (score 0):

This just drove me insane for ten minutes, so I'd like to share my "fix" for any future answer hunters... I was reworking a really old presentation, and someone jacked up a setting. it wasn't in the "custom slide show" menu, but the "Set Up Slide Show" menu. someone had toggled a setting to have the show end after slide 41. Swapped it back to "all" and it was good again. Cheers.